# CSS Transition - how to make a text coming from the top side?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a link in html with some css transition.
I want to change the background color and the color of the text and this is my actually working code:

```
.tdNavBar {
    background-color: #912b3d;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
    -moz-transition: color .4s,background-color .4s;
    transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
}

.tdNavBar:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #912b3d;
    text-align: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 28px;
    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
    -moz-transition: color .4s,background-color .4s;
    transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
}
```

But I want to do one more thing: i want an animation that makes the text comes from top on hover with the new color and replaces the old text, but i don't have idea how to make this.

JSFIDDLE:[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/rthgcort/)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please ?

Comment: Ok now you have the link to js fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `clip` property:

```css
.tdNavBar {
  background-color: #912b3d;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 28px;  
  line-height: 28px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
}
.tdNavBar:before, .tdNavBar:after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}
.tdNavBar:after {
  background-color: white;
  color: #912b3d;
  clip: rect(auto,auto,0px,auto);
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: clip .4s;
  -moz-transition: clip .4s;
  transition: clip .4s;
}
.tdNavBar:hover:after {
  clip: rect(auto,auto,28px,auto);
}
```

```html
<p class="tdNavBar" title="Hover Me"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pseudo effects for this:

*This edited snippet will currently work **only for set text** currently.*

```css
.tdNavBar {
  background-color: #912b3d;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
  -moz-transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
  transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
}



.tdNavBar:before {
  content: "I'm Hovered";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size:0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  z-index: 2;
  transition: all .4s;
}
.tdNavBar:hover:before {
  height: 100%;
  font-size:inherit;
  color:black;
}
.tdNavBar:hover {
  color: transparent;  
}
```

```html
<button class="tdNavBar">Hover Me</button>
<button class="tdNavBar">Hover Me as well</button>
```

---

If you wanted to 'change' the text, you could do something like:

```css
.tdNavBar {
  background-color: #912b3d;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
  -moz-transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
  transition: color .4s, background-color .4s;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  displaY: inline-block;
}
.part1,
.part2 {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transition: all .3s;
  text-align: center;  
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.part2 {
  top: -100%;
}
.tdNavBar:hover .part2 {
  top: 0;  
  background-color: white;
}
.tdNavBar:hover .part1 {
  
  top:200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="tdNavBar">
  <div class="part1">part 1</div>
  <div class="part2">hovered</div>
</div>

<div class="tdNavBar">
  <div class="part1">another link</div>
  <div class="part2">it hovers too?</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, u are on the right way, but with your code i see the background coming from top. I want the same effect but for the text. Can you modify?